# How to fix only fix a bootstrap menu at the top on scroll

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap menu that is fixed at the top my website but I do not want it to be fixed at the top except when it is scrolled. What i mean is that, when you visit the website, the menu should be let's says under `<div id='menu'>  </div>` but when you scroll then it will move to the top as it is already now in my code

This is the code for my menu which is already at the top now

```
<!-- Navigation and Menu-->
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

      <!-- Originaly it had this class="navbar-brand" -->



    <!--  
      <a  class="navbar-brand"   href="index.php" rel="charger_tout" data-ajax="id_du_milieu" data-icon="Oui">


       <img src="media/uploads/images/PCI_sm.png" style="width:120px;height:120px;"> 




<img src="images/my_logo_transparent.png" alt=""     class="img-responsive">




</a>

-->


    </div>


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">













      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown menu-withdraw ">
      <a href="index.php" rel="charger_tout" data-ajax="id_du_milieu" data-icon="Oui">
        <i class='fa fa-home' style='color:initial'></i>  

       Home      


        </a>
    </li>



    <li class="dropdown menu-withdraw ">
      <a href="about.php">


        About



               </a>




    </li>


    <li class="dropdown menu-withdraw">
      <a href="articles-pmg-mission-and-vision.php">
         Vision and Mission       </a>

    </li>


    <li class="dropdown menu-withdraw">
      <a href="articles-pmg-ceo.php">
         The CEO       </a>

    </li>












    <li class=" ">
      <a href="contact-us.php" rel="charger_tout" data-ajax="id_du_milieu" data -icon="Oui">


   Contact      


         </a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown menu-withdraw ">
      <a href="shop.php" title="Patron Shop" rel="charger_tout" data-ajax="id_du_milieu" data-icon="Oui">
       <i class="fa fa-fw fa-shopping-cart"></i>  P-Shop         </a>

    </li>




      </ul>





       <div class="input-group">  &nbsp; </div>



       <?php
    /*
      <!-- Mobile Search -->
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right visible-xs" role="search" method="get" action="post-theme-default">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="title">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme-primary" type="button">Search!</button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </form>

        */

     ?>   


    </div>

    <!--/.nav-collapse -->


  </div>
</div> 
<!-- / .navigation -->


<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".navbar-collapse > ul.navbar-nav > li").each(function() {
            var obj = $(this).find('ul > .active');
            if (obj.length > 0) {
                $(this).addClass('active');
                obj.removeClass('active');
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Question**

In the code above, the menu is fixed at the top but i do not want it to be at the top automatically but to go to the top after the user has scrolled . How to achieve that ?

I want a nav bar that will react like the one use by [smint](http://www.outyear.co.uk/smint/). The nav bar will only go to the top on scroll. Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kressly/79feLhek/1/) of what I already have.

Comment: As per my understanding, Bootstrap only supports top or bottom navigation bar.

Comment: Do you mean it is impossible ? Because what I am trying to do is something like this http://jsfiddle.net/yeco/4EcFf/ only that I want to get that done with my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var distance = $('#menu').offset().top; 

    $(window).scroll(function () {

         if ($(window).scrollTop() >= distance) {
             $('#menu').addClass("navbar-fixed-top");
         } else {
             $('#menu').removeClass("navbar-fixed-top");
         }
     });
```

remove your navbar-fixed-top class and  try this js

Comment: I did that but it did not work completely. The menu was fixed in the page but when i scroll and the menu reached the top, it did not remain fixed on the top. You can see the Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/kressly/79feLhek/3/

Comment: Come on now. Now that's what I am talking about. You rock

Answer (score 0):

This link might help you.

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/create-stay-on-top-menu-css3-jquery/

```
<div id="navi">
    <div id="menu" class="default">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Development</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Freebies</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">WordPress</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- close menu -->
</div><!-- close navi -->
```

Comment: What I want is to modify my code not to change my existing code. My existing code is already at the top. My question is how to make it not be at the top but be at the top only on scroll ?

Comment: I have created this fiddle but i am new with fiddles. http://jsfiddle.net/kressly/79feLhek/1/  As you can see the menu is on the top instead of being after the last Text before the menu is here . I want the menu to be after "Text before the menu is here" and move to the top on scroll